# Is there an elegant way to handle the '\n' that gets read by input functions (getchar(), fgets(), scanf()) in C?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, fgets, getchar

I am trying a simple exercise from K&R to append **string2** at the end of **string1** using pointers. In case of overflow i.e. buffer of **string1** can't contain all of **string2** I want to prompt the user to re-enter **string2** or exit.

I have written the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
int get_input(char *s);
int str_cat(char *s, char *t);

void main()
{
    char input1[MAXLINE], input2[MAXLINE], c; 
    get_input(input1);
    check:
    get_input(input2);
    if((strlen(input1) + strlen(input2) + 2) <= MAXLINE)
    {
        str_cat(input1, input2);
        printf("%s\n", input1);
    
    }
    else
    {
        input2[0] = '\0';
        printf("String overflow\n Press: \n 1: Re-enter string. \n 2: Exit.\n");
        scanf(" %d", &c);
        if(c == 1){
            input2[0] = '\0';
            get_input(input2);
            goto check;
        }

    }

}

int get_input(char *arr)
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    while(fgets(arr, MAXLINE, stdin))
    {
        break;
    }
}
int str_cat(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        s++;
    }
    while((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
    {
        ;
    }
    *s = '\0';
}
```

Initially, I was using the standard `getchar()` function mentioned in the book to read the input in `get_input()` which looked like this:

```
int get_input(char *arr)
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        *arr++ = c;
    }
    *arr = '\0';
}
```

- I am new and I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) and understood my mistake. I understand that one isn't supposed to use different input functions to read stdin and the `'\n'` is left in the input stream which is picked by the `getchar()` causing my condition to fail.
- So, I decided to use `fgets()` to read the input and modified the `scanf("%d", &c)` as mentioned in the thread with `scanf(" %d", c)`. This does work (kinda) but gives rise to behaviors that I do not want.

So, I have a few questions:

1. What's a better way to `fgets()` from reading the input on encountering `'\n'` than the one I have used?

   ```
    while(fgets(arr, MAXLINE, stdin))
    {
        break;
    }
   ```
2. `fgets()` stops reading the line and stores it as an input once it either encounters a `'\n' or EOF`. But, it ends up storing the `'\n'` at the end of the string. Is there a way to prevent this or do I have to over-write the `'\n'` manually?
3. Even though I used the modified version of `scanf(" %d", &c)`, my output looks like
   this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5aX4.jpg). Despite that I get `Enter the string:`  twice when prompted to re-enter the second string in case of an overflow situation. Is the modified `scanf()` messing with my input? And how do I correct it?

Comment: You don't need to add the space in `scanf(" %d", &c)` because the specifiers `%d` and `%f` and `%s` (and their variants) filter leading whitespace automatically. You *do* need the space with `%c` and `%[...]` and `%n`, because otherwise they read every character. Understanding how different formats handle whitespace is key to avoiding nasty kludges.

Comment: As for the newline retained by `fgets` (if room in the buffer) please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) for a bullet proof one-liner.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I noticed that you have put a lot of effort into making your first question a well-written one, and I just wanted to thank you for that.

Comment: If you might need to reject input (or there is a chance the user will type garbage) don't use `scanf`, get input into a string with `fgets` and parse it with `sscanf` or other. If you need to reject the input it is far, far simpler than with `scanf` possibly having its buffer blocked by garbage: you just input another string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, do not mix `fgets` with `scanf`. Although it may be a bit bloaty, you will avoid many problems by being consistent with reading input with `fgets` and then parse it with `sscanf`. (Note the extra s)

A good way to remove the newline is `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0`

Example:

```
// Read line and handle error if it occurs
if(!fgets(buffer, buffersize, stdin)) {
    // Handle error
}

// Remove newline (if you want, not necessarily something you need)
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

// Parse and handle error
int val;
if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &val) != 1) {
    // Handle error
}

// Now you can use the variable val
```

There is one thing here that might be dangerous in certain situations, and that is if `buffer` is not big enough to hold a complete line. `fgets` will not read more than `buffersize` characters. If the line is longer, the remaining part will be left in stdin.